# How to find answers to questions that have been asked before, but never answered?

Tags: support, questions, duplicate-questions, meta

I recently stumbled across an old account of mine that I've lost access to, and filled out the form to have it merged.

I was confused by the instructions, just like the askers of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161313/helpmerge-is-asking-for-something-impossible) and its [duplicates](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166800/user-merge-page-wording).

The questions are unanswered, but I'd like to know the answer (and, apparently, so would others). Clearly this is an answerable question... either it's like that by mistake, and should be fixed, or it's like that for a reason, and an explanation can be given. Duplicating those questions doesn't seem like the right approach, I'm sure it would just get closed as another duplicate.

So, what's the proper way to investigate things that have been asked before, but not answered? I'd bump the other question, but I have nothing significant to add to the question, and don't have an answer.

Edit: The answer to the question marked as a duplicate does not apply here, for reasons I've already explained (I have nothing to add to that question; also, it's not mine. Further, the question discussed there apparently had answers, the question discussed here has none).

Comment: You could try it with a bounty. But of course there is no guarantee that anybody will respond to it.

Comment: @chris, I suppose that could work, but it seems like a bit of a sledgehammer for this particular nut. Any other thoughts?

Comment: I think if you edit your question it will also be shown again, e.g., in the "interesting" tab. Of course an edit should also improve the question somehow (but that could just mean formatting, spelling, etc.)

Comment: @chris it wasn't my question to begin with, but I really don't have anything to significant add... that user already phrased it better than I probably could have. Maybe a new question tagged [tag:discussion] or [tag:support] would not be considered a duplicate, since that one is tagged [tag:bug]?

Comment: @TheCommunity - please don't get hung up on which required tag has been used.

Comment: @ChrisF, alright, good to know. See my edits regarding the alleged duplicate.

Comment: @TheCommunity that it's not your question does not change much. You can still award a bounty if you want it to get more attention.

Comment: @Bart, that was more of an aside than anything. My main point was that *I have nothing to add to that question*, which was central to the answer of the question marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't see how the dupe does not address your question. If you have nothing to add, all you have is a bounty. That's it. If that does not address your issue, please clarify this in your question. Then we can evaluate if this needs to be reopened or not. Now I see no reason to do so.

Comment: @Bart, don't worry about it, the answer here already provided a good solution (that wasn't listed there). I'm just glad Caleb was able to squeeze it in before this was closed.

Comment: @TheCommunity Okay, fair enough. I'm assuming mostly the last paragraph if of value to you? I'll have a look later on if the duplicate could use some extra information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, upvote the question you think would be useful to have an answer to.

Next, post a bounty. Even a measly 50 point bounty will put the question in a separate tab that more people will come across and be likely to review. This is a great way to get eyes on a real problem.

Lastly, depending on the wording of the question, on meta sites it is sometimes appropriate to add an answer that boils down to "I'm having this problem too." If the question is worded in such a way that leaves doubt about whether there actually is a problem (Say "Is X broken and should it be fixed" as opposed to "How do I do X") adding an answer in which you confirm the nature of the problem could be a good thing. I would use the space to suggest a solution. Does a step need to be eliminated? Are the directions just unclear? What would fix the problem for you? If you can answer these questions in an answer, you are likely to gain more rep than you dropped on the bounty. Answering will also bump the question.

Comment: I'm going to trust you on this and add an answer; we'll see where it goes. Upvoting makes sense. I think I'll save the bounty as a last resort. I don't care much about 50 meta points, but I'd just as soon keep them. ;)